# How does back reference to a matching group inside the group itself work in regex?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, backreference

I am trying to understand a regex in Java that finds if a string of ANY length is a palindrome or not, as below:

```
\A(?:(.)(?=.*?(\1\2?)\z))*?.?\2\z
```

It matches a palindrome of all lengths. Can someone explain how is it exactly working? Specifically this part:

```
(?=.*?(\1\2?)\z))
```

wherein the second capturing group(\1\2?) is back-referenced within itself(\2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew IMO it's valid and interesitng question. And it is definitely NOT duplicate of what you posted and doesn't qualify as question mentioned there.

Comment: This regex doesn't seem right. It also accepts `aaba`.